# Replace a character many times

Tags: javascript, arrays, char, str-replace, arabic

in fact, i have to treat a Arabic characters in javascript but i want to show you an example of what i want:

i have this char:

var char = "KASSAB";

i want to get an array of chars by replacing the letter "A" in "1" "2" "3" everytime, so if i have 2 letters "A" in one char, it must be like that:

K**1**SS**1**B,K**1**SS**2**B, K**1**SS**3**B, K**2**SS**1**B, K**2**SS**2**B, K**2**SS**3**B, K**3**SS**1**B, K**3**SS**2**B, K**3**SS**3**B

Any suggestions Please :( ?

Comment: You want a permutation list?

Comment: Does it always have to check for the letter A, or should it be up to the code that calls it?

Comment: Yes @Nate, every time, if it find 2 times the letters A, so permutation by 1, 2, 3, normally i must get 9 char in my array as the example above.

Comment: That's not what I'm talking about. Does it just have to check for the letter A, or should it also check for the other vowels (E, I, O, U, Y?)

Comment: Just the letter A, or a, or á

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a recursive function, as follows:

```
var initialInput = 'KASSAB',
    replaceables = ['A', 'a', 'á'],
    replacements = ['**1**', '**2**', '**3**'];

function indexOfFirstReplaceable(input) {
    var firstIndex = input.length;
    for (var i in replaceables) {
        var index = input.indexOf(replaceables[i]);
        if (index !== -1) firstIndex = Math.min(firstIndex, index);
    }
    return firstIndex < input.length ? firstIndex : -1;
}

function replaceAllAs(input) {
    var index = indexOfFirstReplaceable(input);
    if (index === -1) return [input] // Nothing to replace

    var outputs = [];
    for (var i in replacements) {
        var nextInput = input.substr(0, index) + replacements[i] + input.substr(index + 1);
        outputs = outputs.concat(replaceAllAs(nextInput));
    }
    return outputs;
}

console.log(replaceAllAs(initialInput));
```

will output

```
["K**1**SS**1**B", "K**1**SS**2**B", "K**1**SS**3**B", "K**2**SS**1**B", "K**2**SS**2**B", "K**2**SS**3**B", "K**3**SS**1**B", "K**3**SS**2**B", "K**3**SS**3**B"]
```

EDIT:

Or if you want to be more functional, using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
var initialInput = 'KASSAB',
    replaceables = ['A', 'a', 'á'],
    replacements = ['**1**', '**2**', '**3**'];

function indexOfFirstReplaceable(input) {
    return replaceables.reduce(function (currentMin, replaceable) {
        var index = input.indexOf(replaceable);
        if (index === -1 || currentMin === -1) return Math.max(index, currentMin);
        else return Math.min(currentMin, index);
    }, -1);
}

function replaceAllAs(input) {
    var index = indexOfFirstReplaceable(input);
    if (index === -1) return [input]; // Nothing to replace

    var outputs = replacements.map(function (replacement) {
        var nextInput = input.substr(0, index) + replacement + input.substr(index + 1);
        return replaceAllAs(nextInput)
    });
    return [].concat.apply([], outputs);
}

console.log(replaceAllAs(initialInput));
```

EDIT 2:

To accommodate the overlap of replaceables and replacements you need to specify the `fromIndex` when using `indexOf`:

```
var initialInput = 'KASSAB',
    replaceables = ['A', 'a', 'á'],
    replacements = ['A', 'a', 'á'];

function indexOfFirstReplaceable(input, fromIndex) {
    return replaceables.reduce(function (currentMin, replaceable) {
        var index = input.indexOf(replaceable, fromIndex);
        if (index === -1 || currentMin === -1) return Math.max(index, currentMin);
        else return Math.min(currentMin, index);
    }, -1);
}

function replaceAllAs(input, fromIndex) {
    var index = indexOfFirstReplaceable(input, fromIndex);
    if (index === -1) return [input]; // Nothing to replace

    var outputs = replacements.map(function (replacement) {
        var nextInput = input.substr(0, index) + replacement + input.substr(index + 1);
        return replaceAllAs(nextInput, index + 1);
    });
    return [].concat.apply([], outputs);
}

console.log(replaceAllAs(initialInput, 0));
```

will output

```
["KASSAB", "KASSaB", "KASSáB", "KaSSAB", "KaSSaB", "KaSSáB", "KáSSAB", "KáSSaB", "KáSSáB"]
```

Comment: Dear @Kaarel, thanks for you answer ! i worked fine, but i tried it like that: replaceables = ['A', 'a', 'á'],
    replacements = ['A', 'a', 'á'];
result: too much recursion ..
i want from this example to do that, every time it find an 'A' or 'a' or 'á', replace them with those letters 'A', 'a', 'á' example:
KASSáb so result: KASSAB, KASSab, KASSáb, KaSSaB, KaSSAB, KaSSáB, KáSSáB, KáSSaB, KáSSAB

Comment: @SiMoKassab, to accommodate the overlap of replaceables and replacements you need to specify the fromIndex when using indexOf. I edited my response accordingly.